Migrate code using isFault method to Camel3
I'm migrating a  project that's making use of the isFault method. However, the migration guide mentions, "The fault API has been removed from org.apache.camel.Message as it was only used for SOAP-WS fault message. The camel-cxf and camel-spring-ws components for SOAP-WS has been modified to support fault messages from their components. The option handleFault has also been removed and you now need to turn this on as endpoint or component option on camel-cxf or camel-spring-ws."
This thread mentions we can remove the line safely. setFault() method in Message no longer exists
But I need to use this method and can someone please direct me to an example of achieving the same with camel-cxf as mentioned in the guide.
